# Avoiding code duplication when loading parameters

Tags: duplicates

I have a question regarding trying to avoid code duplication. I have a scenario class, this class contains a set of objects, and these objects are then used to run the algorithm. I use the scenario class to pass it to the necessary objects, and I find myself with several 'loading' of these parameters. Something like this

```
allEMCameraMotions = scenario.getEMCams();
gTObject = scenario.getGroundTruth();
visualCov = gTObject.getVisualCov();
eMCov = gTObject.getEMCov();
tempCov = formTemporalCovariance(gTObject, toEstimateWindowSize);
intrinsics = gTObject.getIntrinsics();
```

I have noticed that this is repeated in several functions inside, and I would like to know if there is out there any strategy to avoid this duplication.

Thank you!

Comment: you mean to say that use of `gTObject` is duplicated @Marcel

Comment: No, what I mean is that the whole piece of code is repeated everywhere I am working with this 'scenario' class.

Comment: i see only functions to reduce your duplicate code and returns all variables @Marcel

Comment: That is the thing, if you use a function here to return all this, you have to have several outputs, and that makes the function quite horrible. I know this is not a big deal, I am just trying to understand if there is a way to reduce it.